# [SOLVED ]Problems adding items in Many to Many relationship in Spring

Tags: spring, many-to-many, thymeleaf

I'm a bit desperate with this, because I assume I'm doing something wrong, but I can't find what is it. I've looked for the answer, but none of them can resolve it.

I have 2 entities with a many to many relatioship, but when I try to add an item to one of them, it is impossible. Symply it is not being added to the DB.

One of them id Formador, and the other is Proveedor. Just wanting to asign one (ore more) Proveedor items to Formador (formador.proveedores)

The entities are as follows:

Formador (only the relationship and constructor)

```
    @ManyToMany (mappedBy = "formadores")
    private List <Proveedor> proveedores;
    
    
    //CONSTRUCTORES
    
    public Formador() {}

    public Formador(Long idFormador, String nifFormador, String passFormador, String nombreFormador, String ap1Formador,
            String ap2Formador, String direccionFormador, int cpFormador, String localidadFormador,
            String provinciaFormador, String tel1Formador, String tel2Formador, String mail1Formador,
            String mail2Formador, String cuentaBancariaFormador, List<Visita> visitas, List<Zona> zonas, Rol rol,
            List<Formacion> formaciones, List<Comercial> comerciales, List<Proveedor> proveedores)
```

Proveedor (same)

```
@ManyToMany (fetch = FetchType.LAZY,  cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinTable(
        name = "formadores_proveedores",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_proveedor"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_formador"))
private List <Formador> formadores;

//CONSTRUCTORES

public Proveedor() {}

public Proveedor(Long idProveedor, String nombreProveedor, List<Campagna> campagnas, List<Franquicia> franquicias,
        List<Zona> zonas, List<Tienda> tiendas, List<Formacion> formaciones, List<Formador> formadores)
```

Formador Controller

```
@GetMapping("/formadorAsignaProveedor/{idFormador}")
public String asignarProveedorFormador(@PathVariable("idFormador") Long idFormador, Model model) {  
    
    Formador formador = null;
    if (idFormador != null) {
        formador = formadorService.findOneFormador(idFormador);
    }
    else{
        return "redirect:/index";
    }
    
    Proveedor proveedor = new Proveedor();
    List <Proveedor> listaProveedores = formadorService.findAllProveedores();
    model.addAttribute("proveedores", listaProveedores);
    model.addAttribute("proveedor", proveedor);
    model.addAttribute("formador", formador);

    return "/formadorAsignaProveedor";
}

@PostMapping("/formadorAsignaProveedor/{idFormador}")
public String formadorGuardaAsignacionProveedor (@PathVariable("idFormador") Long idFormador, Proveedor proveedor, Model model) {       
    Formador formador = null;
        if (idFormador != null) {
            formador = formadorService.findOneFormador(idFormador);
        }
        else{
            return "redirect:/index";
        }
    formador.getProveedores().add(proveedor);
    formadorService.saveFormador(formador);
    model.addAttribute("formador", formador);
    return "redirect:/formadorVer/" + idFormador;
}
```

The web:

```
    <form th:action="@{/formadorAsignaProveedor/} + ${formador.idFormador}"
                th:object="${proveedor}" th:method="POST">
                <div class="form-row mt-2">
                    <div class="col-4 mt-2">
                        <select id="proveedorFormador" class="form-control"
                            th:field="*{idProveedor}">
                            <option th:each="proveedor:${proveedores}"
                                th:text="${proveedor.nombreProveedor}"
                                th:value="${proveedor.idProveedor}"></option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row mt-2">
                    <div class="col-4 mt-2">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Asignar">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

SOLUTION:

The solution was not obvious for me: as I was working woth the entity Formador (in which I was making the changes), I put it as the owner of the relationship.

So i change the model like this:

Formador

```
@ManyToMany (fetch = FetchType.LAZY,  cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinTable(
        name = "formadores_proveedores",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_formador"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_proveedor"))
private List <Proveedor> proveedores;
```

Proveedor

```
@ManyToMany (mappedBy = "proveedores")
private List <Formador> formadores;
```

Thank You all!

Comment: are you using Spring Data jpa or plain hibernate ?

Comment: Im using Spring Jpa